# What does 勾过来 (gōu guòlái) mean in 你就直接勾过来，我觉得欠妥?

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning-in-context

A Mandarin Corner [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTSfPXvrNAw) describes "3 Things Chinese Like about Foreigners" (actually it does the opposite).  One snippet from this dialogue is the following:

[image: 你就直接勾过来，我觉得欠妥。]

I transcribe the conversation as follows (and I'm asking about the part in bold):

> 比如说我跟你还不熟，然后你是一个外国小伙子，我是一个中国小女孩，你就直接**勾过来**，我觉得欠妥。
>   <sub>Bǐrú shuō wǒ gēn nǐ hái bù shú, ránhòu nǐ shì yīgè wàiguó xiǎohuǒzi, wǒ shì yīgè zhōngguó xiǎo nǚhái, nǐ jiù zhíjiē **gōu guòlái**, wǒ juédé qiàntuǒ.</sub>

Which I think (fairly directly) translates to

> For example me and you are not familiar, then you are a foreign young lad and I'm a Chinese girl; you just **"hook up"**; I feel is inappropriate.

I'm uncertain about "hook up"; my best guess is based on the definitions:

- [勾](http://dict.cn/%E5%8B%BE) (gōu) = hook; and
- [过来](http://dict.cn/%E8%BF%87%E6%9D%A5) (guòlái) = come over.

However,  it appears the two (hypothetical) people are unfamiliar with one another, so they're wouldn't hook up so easily.  It could mean something else like "come over with the intention of hooking up" or maybe 勾 doesn't have any special meaning.

**Question**: What does 勾过来 mean in this sentence?

Comment: when following a verb 勾 in the present case 过来 functions as compound direction complement 复合趋向补语，see examples for II  cmp. below
过来 bkrs：＃６２０I v.
come over/up; come here
你过来一下。 Come over here for a moment.
**II cmp.**
1) indicating action toward one
他走过来了。 He's coming over here.
请转过来。 Please turn around (toward me).
2) initiating a new condition
他终于觉悟过来了。 He finally saw the light.
3) with de/bu, indicating ability/inability
孩子多了照顾不过来。 If you have too many children, you won't be able to take good care of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

勾过来 is colloquial. It can be considered as the short version of 勾引过来.  勾引 means *entice, seduce, or tempt*. 过来 here is a  complement.

Your interpretation *come over with the intention of hooking up* for 勾 is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

比如说我跟你还不熟，
For example, you and I do not know each other,
然后你是一个外国小伙子，
you are a young non-Chinese guy,
我是一个中国小女孩，
I'm a young Chinese girl,
你就直接勾过来，（勾搭：（try to) seduce)
you directly come on to me / hit on me / flirt with me
我觉得欠妥。
I feel that is inappropriate

http://www.zdic.net/c/e/143/314164.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think 勾 here means "hooking your arm around my shoulders/neck" similar to how it's used in 勾肩搭背 which basically means the same thing.

This refers to some people being 自來熟 which means thinking oneself as being very close to someone who they just met.